# How to verify links and click on them in Selenium webdriver Java

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I am new in selenium. I have similar links on the page with similar xpaths (let's say links 1 to 30). I need to verify that all of them are present on the page (I want selenium to print something like this "element 1 is present" for each element) and all of them are clickable(new page will opens). 
  So far I have this code to click on all links one by one and print their titles:

```
    driver.get("http://anysite.com");
    String part1=".//*[@id='footer']/div/div[1]/div[2]/ul/li[";
    String part2="]/a";
    for (int i=1;i<=30;i++){
    String text = driver.findElement(By.xpath(part1+i+part2)).getText();
    System.out.println(text);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(part1+i+part2)).click();
    System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
    driver.get("http://anysite.com");
```

Also I have this code to verify presence of each individual link separately (if I have 30 links I have to duplicate this code 30 times):

```
    if(driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@id='footer']/div/div[1]/div[2]/ul/li[1]/a")).size() != 0){
      System.out.println("Element Link 1 is Present");
      }else{
      System.out.println("Element Link 1 is Absent");
      }
```

So far I have two test cases, is there is any way to combine this two pieces together in one nice piece? 
Thank you!

Comment: I've read this over a couple of times, and I don't understand what you are asking.  Can you show, say, 3 instances of the duplicate code?

Answer (score 0):

In String 1 you are taking xpath as:

```
String part1=".//*[@id='footer']/div/div[1]/div[2]/ul/li[";
```

while it should be:

```
String part1="//*[@id='footer']/div/div[1]/div[2]/ul/li[";
```

You need to remove dot "." from your xpath.